# Here is another interesting person

Tags: word, knowledge

This is a compound word

> Made up of three consecutive verbs, two in the past tense
>
> Starts with a noun and ends with a noun
>
> Starts with a metal, ends with kind of metal
>
> Starts with a number, ends with a number

Can you guess?

Hint

> The person competes

Comment: Is this a person's proper name or a person's title?

Comment: Not a proper name. Title I guess like lawyer or doctor

Comment: Is it an open or closed compound word?

Comment: A single non hyphenated word

Comment: Done. Edited to explain more

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Candidate

Made up of three consecutive verbs, two in the past tense

> Can + did + ate (the second and third are in the past tense).

Starts with a noun and ends with a noun

> Starts with **can** and ends with **date**

Starts with a metal, ends with kind of metal

> **Ca** is the chemical symbol for calcium, a metal 
>  **Te** is the chemical symbol for Tellurium, a metalloid.

Starts with a number, ends with a number

> **C** is the Roman numeral for 100 
>  **ate** sounds like *eight* (or possible *e*, as suggested by JonMark Perry)

Hint

> Competitor is synonymous with candidate

Comment: e is a number too